# Mute/Unmute call from notification bar

Tags: applications, calls, mute

I be on meeting calls for long hours.  I usually mute/unmute call by pressing home and then use call app to mute.

I want some app which can provide me functionality to mute /unmute using notification bar.

I have tried many app but none is providing this functionality.

Handset: Micromax Canvas Nitro A310

**OS: Android 4.4 Kitkat **

Comment: What kind of phone do you have?  OS?

Comment: I think this is Android enthusiastic so the os is same

Comment: Yes, I figured it was Android, but the version can matter on different features.

Comment: I have updated in question,  sorry I missed that

Comment: Device is still missing. Some manufacturers/ROMs include special features, like "muting" a call by simply turning the device around (facing with the display down).

Comment: I have updated the same

Comment: @AnonymousMohit: you can simply press `volume down` button of device